# multiprocessing.pool.Pool/ThreadPool can create workers lazily?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I'd like declare my `ThreadPool` globally in my program.

However, `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` creates worker threads greadily, creating them even if no jobs are submitted to the pool. This causes various sorts of problems even when I don't end up allocating threads (e.g. PyCharm is utterly unusable for me when I set breakpoints in a multi-threaded program, and also dingleberry zombie processes are left if the process is not shutdown cleanly).

Is there a way to ask `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` to create the threads lazily?

Comment: There is no `multiprocessing.ThreadPool`... do you mean `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`?

Comment: Yes. ..........

Comment: to my knowledge std-lib Pool does not support this feature, however, what is the real problem you are addressing?